# Visual Studio Code - Java - Import Errors and More

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Just starting working on an existing project at work and wanted to use Visual Studio Code as my IDE (I have used it for a recent Rails project and loved it, so wanted to try with Java).

However, whenever I try to open one of the projects I receive a ton of different errors including:

- When importing java.io, java.util, or anything similar, the error:

> "The import of java.io (or java.util) cannot be resolved"

- Existing classes have an error:

> "The implicit super constructor is undefined for default constructor. Must define explicit constructor"

- Other random "cannot resolve to a type" errors.

All of these seem to stem from some sort of setting error I have with VS Code but can seem to find what it is. I have already uninstalled and reinstalled the RedHat plug-in that enables the Java language for VS Code.

I have tried setting the java_home setting in the extension to the direct location of the install but that didn't work. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling java and that also didn't work.

My operating specs are as follows:

- OS: macOS Sierra
- VS Code version 1.15.1
- JDK version 1.8.0.144

Any idea on what may be causing this? Do you think it may be an error in how I have VS Code set up or if it's an error (or rather incompatibility) with how the existing project is set up?

Comment: Spent hours on this too. If you are using Maven, I ended up right clicking on my main "pom.xml", then clicking "Update project configuration". This regenerated my .classpath and .project files and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue.  The solution was to remove everything from VS Code's workspace storage directory, which was located at `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/`.

I found this solution here:  https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Troubleshooting#clean-the-workspace-directory

*Update:*  This can now be done from within VS Code as of Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat Version 0.33.0.  Open the command palette and type "java clean" (see official description in link).

Comment: I was having the same problem, this solution worked for me. Is this something that I can expect to recur?

Comment: I don't have too much experience working with VS Code, but I've had to do this a few times in the last month.

Comment: Where is that folder located on Windows?

Comment: According to the link, you can locate that folder on Windows at `%APPDATA%\Code[ - Variant]\User\workspaceStorage\`

Comment: In my incase it doesn't work after cleaning and restarting the workspace

Comment: In my case, using the "java clean" command did *not* work, but manually deleting the specified folder *did* work.

Comment: java clean yyds!

Comment: not worked for my macOS 13.5.2 (22G91) and VSCode Version: 1.82.0 and java Extension Pack for Java
v0.25.13

Answer (score 41):

As already mentioned previously, you require to clean the project, but that is a bit difficult thing because every folder is a Guid, and you do not know which one to clear, thus requiring you to delete everything. Starting with **0.33.0** version of the plugin you can automatically do that from within the IDE as well, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type, `java clean`, and IDE will show you the suggestion tip for, *Java: Clean the Java language server workspace*. Upon selection, agree and restart the IDE. It will clean the language server workspace for you.

Another approach can be, the Maven tools within the IDE. If you have this plugin installed, you can use the side bar and utilize the Maven project helper options to perform actions like, clean, install, and package etc. For example, here is the project I am having and the options this shows,

[image]

That can be used, graphically, to manage your Maven-based projects. Also, this would work with the **Java Extension Pack**, not sure yet as to how it would behave with other extensions.

Comment: Thanks. It also works well for me by just typing `F1` and get`Java: Clean the Java language server workspace`

Comment: not worked for my macOS 13.5.2 (22G91) and VSCode Version: 1.82.0 and java Extension Pack for Java
v0.25.13

Comment: Not working for mac 13.4.1 and VSCode 1.82. tried every possible ways. A clean install also doesn't help. Each and every Java files showing error. While from terminal mvn clean compile works perfectly.

Answer (score 18):

For me: CMD + Shift + P
Then type "Java: Clean Java language Server Workspace"

Note: This will reload/restart vscode as well.

Update:
This appears to not fix it anymore for me. In my case I am using a gradle project, and needed to set the `rootProject.name` in the `settings.gradle` to be the same as the folder name that the project is in.

Comment: This does not solve from my side :(

Comment: Yes, this use to... now the issue has morphed and is with the settings.gradle.... will update my answer

Comment: where as for maven project?

Comment: Could you provide more details? Tried this, didn't work

Answer (score 6):

Press ctrl+shift+p
then search 'java clean' and click 'java: clean java language server workspace' then click restart IDE.

Comment: Duplicate of [already answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53417381/5730279).

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue after creating a whole Java project in one computer and then trying to run it on another computer.

After doing everything said in the other answers, what really made VS Code compile was to **open each single project java file in VS Code and save it** (a simple Ctrl + S). Maybe there is a simpler way of doing it, but that is what worked for me and I hope this helps anyone stuck in this issue.

Comment: As strange as this may sound, that did actually solve the problem for me as well! Thanks.

Comment: Same, and it's very convenient when you have autosave.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by going to my settings.json and add the following

```
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: This works for me. Issue showed up after I installed Java 21. Don't know if this is the root cause, but just saying.

Answer (score 1):

I found another simple trick at least to get rid of "cannot be resolved to a type" errors which were coming from older workspaces and wrong project files I guess?. I just ran an empty main(), with the body commented out, while still keeping my local package / import commands at the start - no errors. After commenting in again, the project compiled without errors. Perhaps this refreshing effect might also help in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solution did not work for me,
however I solved it by going to my settings.json (CMD + Shift + P -> "Preferences: User Settings") and add the following

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [

{
  "name": "JavaSE-18",
  "path": "/Users/[username]/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home",
  "default": true
},
```

where the path to your JDK could be something else of course

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but the first answer didn't work.
Adding the JAVA_HOME in the settings.json of VScode worked for me.

to open the settings.json: `ctrl`+`cmd`+`p` then type `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`.
Add a new line with

```
"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "<your $JAVA_HOME>",
```

save and reload Vscode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I moved the Visual Studio Code app from Downloads folder to Applications folder and then restarted visual studio and ran java clean. Started working for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had to clean this folder to get it working on Windows

`%APPDATA%\code\Local Storage`

Comment: I could not find this location, can you give absolute path

Answer (score -1):

Nothing can do,
just open this file into new folder and after that run it. It should prperly run now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33924517)