# Visual Studio Code won't recognize non-java imports

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

In my Java application, Visual Studio Code throws the following error for all my non-java imports:

```
package this.is.a.package does not exist (compiler.err.doesnt.exist)
```

This error appeared a few days ago. Before that my projects and imports where working just fine. I tried to reinstall VSC several times, rebooted my Mac and deleted all files in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/` as suggested by this feed ([Visual Studio Code - Java - Import Errors and More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743779/visual-studio-code-java-import-errors-and-more)). The Java application compiles just fine in IntelliJ IDEA. Therefore, the file structure should be correct.

The error appears after the installation of the Java Language Support (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgewfraser.vscode-javac) extension.

Comment: What do you mean by non-java imports?

Comment: Everything that does not start with java. So for instance org.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I solved this issue by deleting the content of the settings.json file and replace it with some standard entries.

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "java.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
    "java.jdt.ls.vmargs": "",
    "java.import.gradle.jvmArguments": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally after uninstalling the Java Language Support the problem was resolved. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

maybe, you can try the "Java Extension Pack" extension in the marketplace. as the 'Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat' under the pack can provide you the ability of compile.