# Visual Studio Code showing "Java 11 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Today Visual Studio Code started showing me a pop-up saying:

> Java 11 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK.

**I need to use the JDK 8** (working on Apache Beam and that's the last supported version). I have been working on that and haven't had any issues until this came up.

I have read through [this article](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements#setting-the-jdk) and implemented the points mentioned there.

Here is my workspace settings on Visual Studio Code (I have double-checked the paths)

```
{
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "disabled",
    "java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
          "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
          "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home",
          "default": true
        },
        {
          "name": "JavaSE-11",
          "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home",
        }
      ]
}
```

Other helpful information:

```
➜ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and

```
➜ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

This started happening today even though I have been running JDK 8 on Visual Studio Code successfully for a while now. I don't remember updating Visual Studio Code, so I'm not sure as to why this is being displayed now since apparently the pop-up has been displayed since mid-April (asked on the *vscode-java* Gitter channel).

Comment: You would start by getting rid of all the config pointing to java 8, surely?

Comment: Please see [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/java/java-on-visual-studio-code-update-june-2020/) - Java 11 is now a requirement.  It looks like you simply have to move everything about *running* VSCode to Java 11.  Note that you can still code for a lower version of Java.

Comment: How to open workspace settings on VSCode ??

Comment: For people who do not want to install Java-11 and keep using java-8. You will have to install previous version of 'Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat
redhat.java" . 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63287737/4987870

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Change from

`"java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home"`

to

`"java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home"`

and keep the rest of the settings as is.

Comment: This is correct. By changing `java.home` to point to JDK 11 and keeping the rest of my workspace config as is (namely `java.configuration.runtimes` with the default to `JavaSE-1.8`) it worked.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I was facing the same issue with Oracle JDK in VS Code. It worked!

Comment: !!! This doesn't cause the extension to use Java 8 to build, even if it is specified as runtime. It will use Java 11 to build. So if you turn on auto build, which is turned on by default, VSCode will continously build your project using java 11. It might happen that both your build toolchain & vscode wll build your project at the same time, into the same target directories, which causes your toolchain to mistankingly thinkg that parts of the project were built using jdk8 - which can cause very weird and unpredicable linking failures. Cost me an afternoon to figure this out.

Answer (score 21):

For future readers. If you are using the extension "Spring Boot Tools" you may get a similar error to this. I had my JAVA_HOME set to java 8 but required java 11 to use the Spring Boot Tools Language Server. It seems that Spring Boot Tools uses whatever your JAVA_HOME environment variable is or in the PATH environment variable, [Spring Project Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/612#issuecomment-807575359). To override your JAVA_HOME variable you'll need to modify the `spring-boot.ls.java.home` setting.

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. `CRTL + ,` to open the settings
3. Search `spring-boot.ls.java.home`
4. Select 'Edit in settings.json'
5. Your Java 11 installation → `"spring-boot.ls.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.10"`
6. Save and restart VS Code

Prereq: Have a Java 11 installation

Comment: "java.home" and env "JAVA_HOME" settings were ignored by boot tool. "spring-boot.ls.java.home" setting works.

Comment: this is called answer thanks man. and hi how did you know this solution? I want to have kind of this sight too

Answer (score 19):

### Not recommended workaround (not future-proof):

One workaround is to downgrade the extension "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" from the most recent version 0.65.0. back to

**vscode-java version 0.64.1**.

*(This is not recommended unless you have restrictions on the JDK version, it is just possible, see the remarks at the bottom. If you can, use the accepted answer of this thread instead.).*

Taken from *[Java 11 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK" #1543](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1543#issuecomment-669895753)*, this is how to install the earlier extension version (thanks go to the GitHub user who posted this):

[image]

Please mind:

This should be relevant only for those who cannot install JDK 11 or higher:

- Due to a 32-bit system (and who by the same time are forced to use an Oracle JDK 8 as their last Oracle version for 32 bit, so that they are not allowed to use the recommended OpenJDK 14 - see *[JDK Requirements](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements#jdk11.requirement)* → click at the top at the `Java Development Kit` link → jump to https://adoptopenjdk.net/)
- Due to restrictions on a 64-bit system:

  - One plausible reason is that you are not allowed to update Gradle and you have a Gradle version below 4.7, see the [github discussion](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1543#issuecomment-765448476) again.
  - One "not that plausible" restriction could be some efficient laziness. You might simply not want to install a new JDK and change the Visual Studio Code settings back to your old JDK only because of a version change of the Java extension :).

You should not do this if you have no important restrictions. The most plausible restriction is that you use Windows 32 bit, which should be relevant only for those who have an old netbook lying around.

In the usual case: upgrade, and then you can still go back to using an older Java version by changing the settings according to *[JDK Requirements](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements#jdk11.requirement)*:

> Do I need to migrate my projects to Java 11?
>
> "NO, you don't! Well, you should, be we're not here to judge. It is
> still possible to compile/run Java applications from Java 1.5 to 14,
> provided the proper java.configuration.runtimes are configured in the
> user's settings.json."

--> This means you can upgrade the extension, install at least Java 11 (JDK 11), and use the Java runtime of your choice <= your installed Java version.

See detailed instructions for Windows 64bit at *["Java 11 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK" #1543](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1543#issuecomment-671106893)*.

Comment: this works for me. don't know how to fix the java 11 stuff

Comment: @pennychan It is not recommended by the extension developers, and yet it is possible. It is actually the usual case to let the users decide whether they want to upgrade on a breaking change. The upgrade was thus strongly criticised (though you can also switch off automatic updates of course, but that is not the standard in vscode), see https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1543#issuecomment-672014274.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly for users who for some reason that out of their hands cannot install Java 11

Comment: After downgrading, the message still appears on "Java: Configure Java Runtime" page. The message disappeared when I downgraded Java Extension Pack (vscjava.vscode-java-pack) to 0.10.0 too.

Answer (score 14):

In Windows,

1. Download and install JDK 11.

[image: Download and install JDK 11]

2. Once the installation is complete, in `C:\Program Files\Java` you'll see something like this

[image: C:\Program Files\Java]

As you can see, we have JDK 11 in `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.8`.

3. Open VSC and go to Settings (CTRL + , or Manage icon (bottom left) > Settings) and search for `javahome`

[image: VSC Settings Java Home]

4. Click in "Edit in settings.json", add `C://Program Files//Java//jdk-11.0.8` to java.home and save the file. You should have something like this

[image: Java Home VS Code Settings]

```
{
    "java.home": "C://Program Files//Java//jdk-11.0.8"
}
```

5. Restart VS Code and you'll see something like this

[image: Security Warning]

> Security Warning! Do you allow this workspace to set the java.home
> variable?   java.home: C://Program Files//Java//jdk-11.0.8

Click allow and you're good to go.

---

*Note*: If you get this error and are reliant on Java 8, [fbricon](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1543#issuecomment-662582525) mentions,

> you can still compile your projects with Java 8. JDK11 is only
> required to run vscode-java.

Answer (score 5):

About the Java 11 requirement:

The Eclipse platform has decided to require Java 11 as the minimum requirement for its September 2020 release. See *[Upgrading the Eclipse SDK target environment for the *September* Eclipse release...](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/eclipse-pmc/msg03821.html)*.

Because *vscode-java* depends on the Eclipse JDT.LS server, that same requirement to *vscode-java*. But the timeline is be more aggressive: Indeed, *vscode-java* usually consumes JDT.LS builds that depend on bleeding edge JDT features, so effectively shipping pre-release versions of Eclipse Platform/JDT. As of July 22nd, 2020, Java 11 is now required for running *vscode-java*.

This is from：https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements#java.configuration.runtimes

Comment: Installing java 14 helped. Thanks for explaination.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same issue and the following change to my *setting.json* file resolved the issue. Big thanks to [this comment on patch notes](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/pull/1524#issuecomment-663730482).

```
"java.home": "C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot",
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
        "path": "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211",
        "default": true
    },
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-11",
        "path": "C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Just uninstall all previous JDKs, i.e., less than or equal to JDK 11.
2. Re-install JDK 11 from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html
3. Make sure your system variable JAVA_HOME points to the latest installed JDK like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8" (for Windows)
4. Restart Visual Studio Code
5. Go to *Workspace settings* → *Java: Home*
6. Select "Edit in settings.json"
7. Your settings.json should look like:

   [settings.json_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS4BC.png)

   ```
   {
       "java.completion.favoriteStaticMembers": [

           "org.junit.Assert.*",
           "org.junit.Assume.*",
           "org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*",
           "org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.*",
           "org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicContainer.*",
           "org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest.*",
           "org.mockito.Mockito.*",
           "org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*",
           "org.mockito.Answers.*"
       ],
       "java.home": "C://Program Files//Java//jdk-11.0.8"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For people who do not want to install [Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11) and keep using [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). You will have to install previous version of extension 'Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat
redhat.java". The extension version should be 0.64.1 for Java 8.

Please refer the answer in the post below -

*[Visual Studio Code showing "Java 11 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043585/visual-studio-code-showing-java-11-or-more-recent-is-required-to-run-please-do/63287737#63287737)*

Comment: You can still compile your projects with Java 8. JDK11 is only required to run vscode-java.

Answer (score 1):

Add this variable in your `settings.json` file.

```
"sonarlint.ls.javaHome": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Adopt open JDK (Eclipse Temurin) for my Gradle builds and switching to VS Code from Android studio encountered with 'There is no valid JAVA_HOME setting to launch Gradle Language Server. Please check your "java.home" setting.'.

Delving into that issue I found **some JDK Installers don't even install Java_Home** by default.

Just reinstalling with fields checked, solved the issue.
Don't forget to restart VS Code. (no need to edit environment variables at least I didn't have to)

[image: error]
[image: fixed]

hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 March,

I found the `java.home` was changed to be recommended to use `java.jdt.ls.java.home`, then just change it.

And one another setting I did to get rid off that message, re-check the environment variables on your machine, does it set to proper Java 11 or above?

After made those settings, restart VS Code and then go on your work.

Answer (score 0):

If VisualSudioCode suggested to install **OpenJDK17U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_xxxx**, later You should select local folder where eEclipse Adptium was already installed.
for example in mine was in "**C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot**"
and re start VSC