# Java 11 or more recent is required to run - Visual Studio cannot debug Java 8 Azure Function

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have VS Code on new Windows machine. I'm opening Azure Java Functions code. It is using Java 8.
I have installed Zulu-8. JAVA_HOME env is set to C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8\

I open VS Code. I press "Start Debugging"

I get ERROR:

```
Java 11 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode showing "Java 11 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043585/vscode-showing-java-11-or-more-recent-is-required-to-run-please-download-and-i)

Answer (score 2):

This [link](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements#java.configuration.runtimes) explains the cause of this problem:

[image]

**Therefore, starting from July 22, 2020, Java 11 is required to run vscode-java.**

If you need to compile your projects against a different JDK version, it's recommended you configure the java.configuration.runtimes property in your user settings, eg:

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-8",
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-11",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-11",
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-14",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-14",
    "default": true
  },
]
```

Comment: What I need to do? Should I remove Java 8 and install 11? How to make Function working version 8 as 11 is not supported with Azure Functions.

Comment: Where I do find java.configuration.runtimes configuration in VS Code? I have installed now Java 11. I get "WARNING] Azure Functions only support JDK 8, which is lower than local JDK version 11.0.8."