# VS Code required Java 11, but Azure Functions require Java 8 - How to modify settings.json

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

Starting July Java 11 was required for Visual Studio Code. So I have installed Java 11.
But Azure Function requires Java 8. I tried to configure VS to use both SDK.

Example: [VSCode showing "Java 11 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043585/vscode-showing-java-11-or-more-recent-is-required-to-run-please-download-and-i)

VS Code still trying to use Java 11. Is it possible to change to JDK 8???
[WARNING] Azure Functions only support JDK 8, which is lower than local JDK version 11.0.8.

JAVA_HOME env path

```
C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-11\
```

Settings.json for JAVA.HOME

```
{
  "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "target/azure-functions/functionsjava",
  "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Java",
  "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~2",
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "package",
  "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "interactive",
  "azureFunctions.templateFilter": "All",
  "java.home": "C:/Program Files/Zulu/zulu-11",
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
      "path": "C:/Program Files/Zulu/zulu-8",
     "default": true
    },
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-11",
      "path": "C:/Program Files/Zulu/zulu-11",
  
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have JAVA_HOME set to 8 and java.home in VS Code set to 11. Seems to work with Azure functions.

Comment: I face the same problem. It still try to use global settings.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use jdk 8, then you should do like this:

```
"java.home":"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_261",
```

By the way, azure function support java 11, but you need you use function v3:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=consumption#supported-versions