# How can I create java project in Vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

when i use vscode to run the java, i can run it successfully. However, the vscode appears this problem which confuses me[image: tue problem]

[image]

Comment: Maybe this link can help you. It's a similar problem [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826895/how-to-avoid-vs-code-warning-myfile-java-is-a-non-project-file-only-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826895/how-to-avoid-vs-code-warning-myfile-java-is-a-non-project-file-only-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the "Extension Pack for Java" in vscode, just press ctrl+shift+p and look for "Java: Create Java Project" or follow this tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial