# Java Error Vs code: (class_Name).java is a non-project file, only syntax errors are reported

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, error-messaging

this error keeps showing while I run any java program on vs code, the program gets executed with no problem but the error keeps showing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid Visual Studio Code warning: "\[myfile\].java is a non-project file, only syntax errors are reported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826895/how-to-avoid-visual-studio-code-warning-myfile-java-is-a-non-project-file-o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of opening file is wrong. The problem is that a single file cannot be recognized as a project. The correct way to open a java file is to open folder first and then the file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to right-click on the parent folder of the file you are working on in your current workspace and then click on "Add Folder To Java Source Path"
[image]