# Cannot be resolved to a type in VS Code [Java]

Tags: java

I am having problems running my `Dog.class` and `DogDemo.java` files in VS Code. I typed it exactly as written in a Java book. I am coming up with the error:

> Dog cannot be resolved to a type
>
> at DogDemo.main(DogDemo.java:7)

I also have tried cleaning the java workspace, but it doesn't work.

**`Dog.class`**

```
public class Dog
{
    public String name;
    public String breed;
    public age = 0;
    

    public void writeOutput()
    {
        System.out.println("Name " + name);
        System.out.println("Breed: " + breed);
        System.out.println("Age in calendar years" + age);
        System.out.println("Age in human years" + getAgeInHumanYears());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public int getAgeInHumanYears()
    {
        int humanAge = 0;

        if (age <= 2) 
        {
            humanAge = age * 11;
        }

        else
        {
            humanAge = 22 + ((age-2) * 5);
        }

        return humanAge;
    }
}
```

**`DogDemo.java`**

```
public class DogDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Dog kumo = new Dog();

        kumo.name = "kumo";
        kumo.age = 42;
        kumo.breed = "Corgi";
        kumo.writeOutput();

        Dog scooby = new Dog();
        scooby.name = "Scooby";
        scooby.age = 9;
        scooby.breed = "Great Dane";
        System.out.println(scooby.name + " is a " + scooby.breed +
        ".");`
        System.out.print("He is " + scooby.age + " years old, or ");

        int humanYears = scooby.getAgeInHumanYears();
        System.out.println(humanYears + " in human years.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Dog-Class you forgot the type for the age variable (probably an integer), so correct it would be:

```
public class Dog
{
    public String name;
    public String breed;
    public int age = 0;
```

And in your DogDemo-class you've got a Typo in the line:

```
System.out.println(scooby.name + " is a " + scooby.breed +
    ".");``
```

The " ' " after the semicolon should be removed to:

```
System.out.println(scooby.name + " is a " + scooby.breed + ".");
```

Then it works just fine for me :) Keep on coding!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to state the type of your variable `age`

```java
    public age = 0;
```

should become

```java
    public int age = 0;
```

In addition on DogDemo.java lines 17-18 you have

```java
        System.out.println(scooby.name + " is a " + scooby.breed +
        ".");`
```

you have a backtick `, which isn't valid and should be removed to become

```
        System.out.println(scooby.name + " is a " + scooby.breed +
        ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Dog

```
class Dog {
    String name;
    String breed;
    int age;

    void writeOutput()
    {
        System.out.println("Name " + name);
        System.out.println("Breed: " + breed);
        System.out.println("Age in calendar years" + age);
        System.out.println("Age in human years" + getAgeInHumanYears());
        System.out.println();
    }

    int getAgeInHumanYears()
    {
        int humanAge = 0;

        if (age <= 2)
        {
            humanAge = age * 11;
        }

        else
        {
            humanAge = 22 + ((age-2) * 5);
        }

        return humanAge;
    }
}
```

DogDemo

```
public class DogDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog kumo = new Dog();

        kumo.name = "kumo";
        kumo.age = 42;
        kumo.breed = "Corgi";
        kumo.writeOutput();

        Dog scooby = new Dog();
        scooby.name = "Scooby";
        scooby.age = 9;
        scooby.breed = "Great Dane";
        System.out.println(scooby.name + " is a " + scooby.breed + ".");
        System.out.print("He is " + scooby.age + " years old, or ");

        int humanYears = scooby.getAgeInHumanYears();
        System.out.println(humanYears + " in human years.");
    }
}
```

The changes I made:

1. removed public keyword from your data class Dog
2. you missed ` on your main function where you are printing out name + breed
3. add type int to the `age` in Dog's property

please also make sure your classes are in the same package or import it into your class if they are not.

**EDIT:**

I think other people also had the same issues as you are having you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743779/visual-studio-code-java-import-errors-and-more)

And also you can follow the steps [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial), this documentation provided by VS code. You can see which steps are missing.

Comment: how do i make my classes in the same package / or import? They're in the same folder.

Comment: @evanparial if they are in the same folder it should be ok, I updated my answer with more info